# Entity Framework query student grade for a specific subject

Tags: database, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 entities:
Student

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
```

Subject

```
    public int SubjectID { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }       
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Grade> Grades { get; set; }
```

Grades

```
    public int GradeID { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public int GradeValue { get; set; }
```

There is Many-To-Many relationship between the Student and Subject classses and there is One-To-Many between Subject-Grade and Student-Grade.

The reason for Student-Grade: there is a situation where I want all grades of a student, regardless of subject to displayed. For Subject-Grade: not every Subject uses the same scale, for example one subject uses a 1-10 scale, another uses 1-100 scale.

What I would like to display however is: all of student1's grades for Math class, for example.

I was thinking that I should first get all grades for a user, then filter the class I want. Or should I join all tables then filter for StudentID and SubjectID?

So my ultimate question, what is how to do this query?

Comment: Generally with EF you just write the query and let it figure out the most efficient way to implement it in SQL. It doesn't get it wrong very often anymore.

Comment: I would modify that design. Explicitly create a "StudentSubject" bridge table. Add Grade reference in there.

Comment: @Rup Sorry I messed up the question part. I'm trouble with writing the actual query.

Comment: @SteveGreene You mean create a StudentSubject with one-to-one relationship for Student and Subject and add some kind of relationship for Grade?

Comment: Yes. Student and Subject would both have 1:M relationships to that table as described [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/12/avoid-many-to-many-mappings-in-orms/)

Comment: var studentsWithMathGrades = context.StudentSubjects
        .Where(ss => ss.Subject.SubjectName == "Math")
  .Select(ss => new { 
   ss.Student.LastName,
   ss.Student.FirstName,
   ss.Grade.GradeName
  })
  .ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, adjust your Grades class.  A Grade is dependent on the intersection between a Student and a Subject.  i.e.

```
public int GradeID { get; set; }
public string GradeName { get; set; }
public int GradeValue { get; set; }    // -1 = class in progress
public int StudentId { get; set; }
public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
public int SubjectId { get; set; }
public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
```

EF will generate keys since you have the navigation paths but relying on inferred keys rather than explicit keys leaves you susceptible to breakage if the default behavior changes (as it often does).  Plus you have control over naming of the keys.

As to the query, you can just use:

```
db.Student.Include("Grades").Include("Grade.Subject").FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == <something>);
```

As you are probably aware, a M-M join requires a "join" table.  In this example, you can use Grades as your M-M join table.  So I would also remove the navigation properties between Students & Subjects.  It can be achieved via the Goals table and the query you use.  The inverse query (students in a class):

```
db.Subject.Include("Grades").Include("Grade.Student").FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == <something>);
```

Comment: I modified my Grade class and it seems it is easier to query now. However, what I specifically like to achieve is: get all grades where SubjectId == X and where StudentID== Y. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Sure, db.Student.Include("Grades").Include("Grade.Subject").FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == Y && s.Grade.Subject.SubjectId == X);

Comment: Actually you can make that simpler.  db.Grades.Include(Student"),Include("Subject").FirstOrDefault(p => p.StudentId == y && p.SubjectId == x)

Comment: Thank you. It say I cant reference Students at this part: && s.Grade.Subject.SubjectId == X); because iif ICollection<Grade> does not contain definition for Subject. However I think this is because I use IQueryable, I guess I have to use something else to work. Anyway I think your solution will work.